# why are ds register restored?

Tags: c, linux, gdb

I write a short program like this:

```
3: int main(int argc ,char **argv){
4:     printf("%d\n", 1);
5:     asm volatile("mov %eax, %ds");
6:     int a=3,b=1;
7:     float c = a/b;
8:     printf("%f\n", c);
9:     return 0;
 }
```

i use gdb to debug it, i watch $ds, after 5th step, $ds have been changed. but when i use 'n', gdb stoped, ds register is restored. Why? Is there side effect of using gdb to debug your program?

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.
1
Watchpoint 2: $ds

Old value = 0
New value = 2
main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe5b8) at hello.c:6
6       int a=3,b=1;
(gdb) n
Watchpoint 2: $ds

Old value = 2
New value = 0
0x0000000000400559 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe5b8) at hello.c:6
6       int a=3,b=1;
```

Comment: Ok, I'm confused.  If `argv=0x7fffffffe5b8`, that looks like 64bit code.  Does `ds` even mean anything there?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd, yes, 64bit, ds mean nothing, the default of ds is 0. but why are the ds restore?

Comment: I don't believe `mov %eax, %ds` actually does anything under 64bit.  My best guess is that it is silently ignored.  In that case, the fact that gdb (momentarily) shows it as changed is a (not very interesting) flaw in gdb.

Comment: related, but also unanswered question: [Why do ES and DS zero out eventually on 64 bit kernel when set to TLS selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32937701/why-do-es-and-ds-zero-out-eventually-on-64-bit-kernel-when-set-to-tls-selectors)